# How do I synchronize files or directories on an Android device with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I'm missing some very basic Ubuntu One usage information, like how to synchronize the files between Ubuntu One, my Android phone, and my Ubuntu 12.04 PC.

Is there a users guide or reference manual someplace?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The simple piece that I was missing was that my computer was not logged into U1, so even tho there were files in the Ubuntu one folder they weren't getting synced. When I right clicked on another folder to sync it, I got a prompt to log in. –

Answer (score 3):

[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en) is an app that lets you sync selected folders between Android and various cloud services, including Ubuntu One. The free version shows ads and limits the number of cloud services you can use simultaneously.

Comment: How frustrating that neither `Dropbox` nor `Ubuntu One` seem to offer this *basic* functionality natively...

Answer (score 2):

The android app can be found [here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files)

The way this works is that everything in the Ubuntu One folder (located in your home folder) is automatically synchronized to the cloud. You can add more folders to be synchronized by right clicking on them in the file manager and navigating to the `Ubuntu One` sub menu and finally clicking `Synchronize This Folder`.

On Android your photos are uploaded to a folder named after the model of your phone (mine is `Pictures - HTC Ruby`), and you can select files to be downloaded from Ubuntu One to your phone. These are not synchronized with their versions in the cloud after download, however.
 You can upload files within the android app by navigating into a folder and hitting the + icon in the right. You will need an app like [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) installed to be able to just select any file from the SD card, however. To do this, select `Add file` after tapping the + icon and select `File Manager` (or your preferred app) from the list.

[image]

To get your pictures or other files in Ubuntu One on your PC you need to use the Ubuntu One app for Ubuntu (Open the dash and type `Ubuntu One`). Select the folders here that you want to sync to your computer:

[image]
The folders in the cloud that you select will be placed in your home folder and synchronized with other computers. For example I sync my scripts so I always have my most current work no matter which machine I turn on.

There is also a music app for Ubuntu One that requires a subscription to work. It can stream your whole music collection to you, which is great if you have an unlimited data plan. It can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nt.sourceforge.subsonic.u1), if you are interested.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Android U1 files client does NOT synchronize files. It allows you to download files to your Android device, but any modifications you make there will not be re-uploaded.

Comment: Full and automatic sync is not available in the "Ubuntu One for Android."  You have to manually choose which files you want to download from the cloud to the Android device. Files can also be uploaded manually, though the process requires a file browsing app like "File Expert."

Comment: So, I can upload a file from android into U1, but if I edit the file on android, it doesn't get synced.  Is there no way to force a synce on a modified file from android?  If I modify the file from linux, it gets synced right away.

Comment: It looks like the work around to get it synced from android is to upload the file again from the /U1 folder.  Seems like something pretty basic that they would have included.

Comment: That would be the only way until they add the feature.

Comment: This is just a question--how do I get the music files on my usb to go to Ubuntu1; what about using Rythmbox to play the cloud files?

Answer (score 0):

Very old post and strangely, Ubuntu One Mobile App still does not support syncing like Ubuntu One desktop App. In mobile devices, it just lets you access what's present in your U1 account. If you download and modify a file, it does not sync back to U1.

As far as third party sync apps are concerned, i don't trust them on the permissions they ask, and the ads they show.

I had the same issue while using Ubuntu One App on my BlackBerry Z10. This solution I came up with, will work for all platforms all devices not just Z10.

It might seem little complicated to use for some users. But here it is.

I have created a very basic shell script to sync a folder(which is already in sync with Ubuntu One App in my Laptop)

Shell script I use to sync the folder with phone memory or memory card :
After connecting my phone using USB mass storage(my memory card name is MICROSD in my case)

The folder ~/MyFolder is already in sync with U1 in my laptop(OS: Ubuntu12.04).

So this goes to:
1. First thing first, the folder i want to be synced with my phone, is already in sync with U1 and my Laptop.

1. I just now have to sync the same folder either from my Laptop or from U1, with my Phone.
2. As I don't know a way to sync a folder directly from U1 with a phone, I'm going to sync the folder on my Laptop with my Phone.

This script syncs folder on my Laptop which is at ~/MyFolder, with the folder in my Z10 memory card at /media/MICROSD/BlackBerry/documents/MyFolder

Replace these paths in the script with relevant paths for you

```
#!/bin/bash
#BB MyFolder Sync

echo "Starting sync with Z10.."
cp ~/MyFolder/* "/media/MICROSD/BlackBerry/documents/MyFolder/" -u -v -a -r -R -p
#add -i for interactive sync, to prompt before overwrite
echo phase 1/2 completed..
sleep 2
cp /media/MICROSD/BlackBerry/documents/MyFolder/* ~/MyFolder -u -v -a -r -R -p
#add -i for interactive sync, to prompt before overwrite
echo phase 2/2 completed..
sleep 60
```

Now save this as SyncMyFolder.sh and check "Allow executing file as program" (just in case you don't know this) under permissions in file properties

All set and you can now connect your phone using mass storage. You can now hit enter on SyncMyFolder.sh and choose "Run in terminal". It'll show you what is being done in the terminal window.
When you see "echo phase 2/2 completed..", the folder is synced.

The only con of this process is that i have to sync my phone this way every night manually. The files I modify on my phone are now synced with U1.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility to sync files from Ubuntu One on your Android Mobile to your PC. However, it means using dropbox to transmit the file temporarily between the SD card and the Ubuntu one folder. That said, I would prefer this method than installing something unknown or messing too much with the configs. At the end of the day your main storage is in Ubuntu and you delete the file to be transported in dropbox later. It's just a temporary transport mechanism but this works to sync from Ubuntu back to the PC then.

Step 1 - open doc with office, edit doc etc.
Step 2 - save as, /storage/sdcard0/u1/Ubuntu One/*folder*
Step 3 - Go to /storage/sdcard0/u1/Ubuntu One/*folder*
Step 4 - Click file and send it to dropbox
Step 5 - Go to Ubuntu and click 'add file' from dropbox folder where you saved
Step 6 - Sync file on mobile device and it will appear on your desktop now in file list
Delete file from dropbox

Please note dropbox's privacy policy.

**5. data retention "there may be latency in deleting information from our servers and backed up versions might exist after deletion"**

Step 2b. You could save it, encrypt it, then send it to dropbox and decrypt it after on your pc or mobile after sync (if you must).