# Ubuntu One on Android doesn't sync files

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I've installed and set up Ubuntu One on 2 Ubuntu machines and one Android. Then I put keewpassx.kdb file in Ubuntu One folder and it apeeared on Android and the second machine.

Then I opened that file with keepassx app on Android and added a new entry to it. Then I exited from keepassxc app (file was saved) and syncronized Ubuntu One on Android.

The first strange thing - Ubuntu One sais that file was modified 21 hours ago, despite I modified it right 1 minute ago

The second strange thing that file wasn't updated on two ubuntu machines.

How does Ubuntu One work after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ubuntu One Files** (Android) application provides follwing features -

- Sync files from Ubuntu One Web to desktop and vice-versa
- Selectively sync files / folders from desktop to Ubuntu One Web
- Download / Upload files or folders to and from Ubuntu One Files app on Android

---

However, it *does not* yet provide feature to -

- Sync versions of files / folders between Android and Web, after they have been synced once.

  > One has to manually re-upload a new version of a file from Android to Web or to Ubuntu One Files App. Similarly, a manual re-download is required from Web to Ubuntu One Files app to have updated file version.

You may also refer to this existing [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196098/how-do-i-synchronize-files-or-directories-on-an-android-device-with-ubuntu-one) for more information.